# Tool to code / label qualitative data, e.g. interview transcripts

Tags: data-analysis

Does anyone know of an efficient tool to apply codes to long text documents, like interview transcripts? I'm currently using Atlas.ti, as we will also use that to further analyze the codes, however, I feel that process of applying the codes to the text is unnecessarily tedious. Main pain points:

- Highlighting of text is accurate to the letter, not automatically enveloping words, such that one needs to be more precise.
- To apply a code, I always need to hit a shortcut (ctrl-j), where I would prefer to just highlight and start typing. (compare adding comments in acrobat pdf, where that is the workflow once the highlighter-tool is selected)
- In addition, I would prefer if there is a way to clearly distinguish between speakers, e.g. greying out the interviewer to focus on the replies (my transcripts have speaker tags at the start of the line, Atlas.ti just doesn't do anything with those)

I know these friction points are tiny, but once the texts are long enough and the number of interviews grows, they do accumulate.

Since Atlas.ti can import codes, does anyone know of a tool that is more efficient for the step of applying codes to the data?